# How to make writing in openpyxl dynamic

Tags: python, loops, openpyxl

I have a script which cycles through rows 2 to 25 of column A and now I want to write something related to every user(column A information) and have it displayed on column B. this all via openpyxl

```
import openpyxl

wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
sheet_obj = wb_obj.active
for col in sheet_obj.iter_cols(min_row=2, max_col=1, max_row=25):
  for cell in col:
    print(cell.value)
    for test in sheet_obj.iter_cols(min_row=2, max_col=2, max_row=25):
          for cel in col:
                sheet_obj[cel] = int(input())
```

at first I tried using this for loop twice to keep track however this doesn't work. it asks the first input however it is not able to work it in the sheet_obj[cel] statement

does anyone have any idea how to get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood the question, but here are a few tips:

If you don't need to style your data in any way I'd recommend using pandas. Something like the example below -

```py
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_excel(...)

# Create your column 'B' here...

df.to_excel(...)
```

If you really need to stick to openpyxl, I'd try iterating through your sheet in another way. Something along the lines of the example below -

```py
    for row in range(2, 25):
        for col in range(2, 25):
            cell = sheet_obj.cell(
                row=row, column=col
            )
            cell.value = int(input())
```

It's what I do on my openpyxl based [lib](https://github.com/Eric-Mendes/unexpected-isaves/blob/main/src/unexpected_isaves/save_image.py#L75).

Sorry for not quite answering it. I tried to just add a comment but I don't have enough reputation for it.

Comment: using your method i managed to get my code to work to the same extent as my own. it cycles the correct places and it asks the first input but after that it crashes with the error message : TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem here is the code I used
first issue was that it expected a string so i used the str command
then my issue was with the way cell gives its information so I tried to get the correct info by using the coordinate subcommand so that i would receive 'B4'instead of cell worksheet B4

code:

```
 for row in range (2,25):
  for col in range(2,3):
    cell = sheet_obj.cell(
      row=row, column=col
      )
    name = sheet_obj.cell(row = row, column =1)
    sheet_obj[str(cell.coordinate)] = int(input())
```

I hope this helps someone who might run into the same issue. extra thanks to Eric Mendes who helped me onto the right track